# Find value or $W=\sqrt[4x+4]{3^{x}\left ( \sqrt{5}-1 \right )}$ according to condition $9^{x}=6^x +4^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, exponential-function, roots, quadratics

If     $$9^{x}=6^x +4^x$$

Find the value of:

$$W=\sqrt[4x+4]{3^{x}\left ( \sqrt{5}-1 \right )}$$

Solving the equation arrives at:

$x = \frac{\log\left ( \sqrt{5}-1 \right ) - \log(2)}{\log(2) - \log(3)}$

**But W yields a giant result,
Is there any algebraic manipulation that I do not see**

Comment: It seems like it should be $W = 2^{1/4}$ (or at least very close to it).

Comment: Compute $\log{W}$. A careful (but straightforward) computation shows that the answer is $\frac{1}{4}\log{2}$, hence $W$ is indeed $2^{1/4}$.

Comment: I found a solution ...It is indeed $ 2^{1/4}$

Comment: I can also concur, that the answer is indeed $2^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$1=\left(\frac23\right)^x+\left(\frac49\right)^x$$
Let $a=\left(\frac23\right)^x$
$$a^2+a-1=0$$
Solving gives
$$a=\left(\frac{\sqrt5 -1}{2}\right)$$
$$\left(\frac23\right)^x=\frac{\sqrt5 -1}{2}$$
$$\left(\frac32\right)^x=\frac{2}{\sqrt5-1}$$
$$3^x=\frac{2^{x+1}}{\sqrt5-1}$$

Substitute for this in question
$$\left(\left(\frac{2^{x+1}}{\sqrt5-1}\right)(\sqrt5-1)\right)^{\frac{1}{4(x+1)}}=2^{\frac{x+1}{4(x+1)}}=2^{1/4}$$

Comment: Thanks, very clear explanation, I already saw the trick